# How to give a unique key value of array to a variable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a variable which is getting value from map method of array, everything is fine , but the console throws a warning

> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

How can i unique key value to a variable ?

```
    const myVar = value.map((items, key) => items.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a key

```
const myVar = value.map((items, key) => <React.Fragment key={key}>items.name</React.Fragment);
```